# Change request path in action filter in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, action-filter

We have an action filter, **ActionAuthorizationFilterAttribute**, that performs some authorization tests (getting its permissions from the session, more on that later) in its **OnActionExecuting** method, and if the tests are ok, it just returns, and if not, it sets **ForbidResult** on the context's **Result** property. So far so good. But we have one case, where the session retruns null for the permissions after some idle time period, and we need to set the request path to **"/"**, instead of the user doing that by hand, so for example if the user is trying to access some url after his session ends, like http://mydomain/mywebapp/someurl, the method should return him to http://mydomain/mywebapp/, and the application will start its session init stuff again. This works when the does this by hand, but it doen't work in the method.  Here's the code for the method:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Trim().ToLower();
        var session = context.HttpContext.Session;
        var permittedUrls = session.GetJson<List<string>>(SesstionStateKeys.PermittedUrls);

        if (permittedUrls == null)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Request.Path = "/";
            return;
        }

        if (permittedUrls.Any(url => path.Contains(url.Trim().ToLower())))
        {
            return;
        }

        context.Result = new ForbidResult(); //new UnauthorizedResult();

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
   var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Trim().ToLower();
   var session = context.HttpContext.Session;
   var permittedUrls = session.GetJson<List<string>>(SesstionStateKeys.PermittedUrls);

   if (permittedUrls == null)
   {
      context.Result = new RedirectResult("your_url");
      return;
   }

   if (permittedUrls.Any(url => path.Contains(url.Trim().ToLower())))
   {
      return;
   }

   context.Result = new ForbidResult(); //new UnauthorizedResult();

   base.OnActionExecuting(context);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ivamax9, but this solution doesn't work. Maybe because we're using our asp.net core controllers as web api controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `Path` in code will not redirect user to new path. You should return `RedirectResult` if you want user to be redirected to index/login page.

For API best option is return `UnauthorizedResult`.

Comment: We aren't using ASP.NET Core MVC. We are using ASP.NET Core with Web API, meaning that our controllers just return data, not views. All the views are handled in the client by Angular and ui-router. Will your solution work with our setup? If so, I need to change the line **context.HttpContext.Request.Path = "/";** to **context.Result = new RedirectResult("/");** ?

Comment: If you want return to your user/client some "instruction" to "make new request to index/login page" - you should return something. Something that your user/client will understand. Something "documented" (in your docs). Without this (only by changing `Request.Path`) only your server will "do" something "other", not client. Client will "think" that his call, say, to "/api/create/magic" executed and magic created, but it's not true if user is unauthorized (due to session/credentials expiration). Imho returning `UnauthorizedResult` is best decision for your case (updated my answer).